# Question about convex function defined on a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that contains $(0,0)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've come to a problem in a multivariate calculus textbook that I'm having trouble with.

The problem goes :

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a convex set containing $(0,0)$ and let
$f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Show that for any
$(x,y) \in D$, we have $(-x,-y) \in D$ and $f(-x,-y) \geq -f(x,y)$.

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the statement correctly? There are plenty of convex sets $D$ which are such that $(x,y) \in D$ but $(-x,-y) \not \in D$. For example you could take $D$ any half a disk centered at the origin.

Comment: I noticed that problem too. I copied it correctly.  Maybe there is a mistake in the book.